# Is it possible to update VirtualBox offline?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, updates

Is it possible to update VirtualBox offline, while preserving the already installed virtual machines and their settings?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - Virtualbox's updates have always been offline & always preserved the existing VMs & settings

Comment: @Sathya, [link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=15429) there seems to be different opinions. I'm not sure about it. If I download and run the latest version from [link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=15429) would it simply replace my old version?

Comment: I uninstalled a previous version today and then installed the latest version and it preserved all my installed VM's along with their settings.

Comment: Awaisj, that linked forum post is rather old and dated. Even so, that post mentions that upgrade doesn't touch user files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualbox's updates have always been offline & always preserved the existing VMs & settings. (Atleast, since the time I started using - ~v2.0 onward I believe).

If you're running an out-of-date-version, VirtualBox may prompt you to download an update - most probably from their [download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Running the upgrade will do an in-place upgrade. The user data - ie, VMs, settings, Virtual disks, images, snapshots will not be touched.